# Problem in using SQL in combining two workbooks with VBA

Tags: sql, excel, vba

I am very new to using SQL with VBA.

I am in a situation where i have two workbooks and i am combining both of them  with one common column using SQL. I made both of the workbooks as database using this [website](https://excel-macro.tutorialhorizon.com/vba-excel-make-excel-file-as-odbc-sourcedatabase-using-microsoft-excel-driver/).

The example i used from internet had me fetching data from one excel file so he simply opened connection to one db, but how should i do it when i want two excel files acting as db. Want to do it so i can run a SQL query combining the two

```vb
 Sub ReadDB()
    Dim mainWorkBook As Workbook
    Dim intRowCounter

    Set mainWorkBook = ActiveWorkbook

    intRowCounter = 2

    mainWorkBook.Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A2:Z100").Clear

    Set Connection = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    Connection.Open "DSN=BDRReport"
    Connection.Open "DSN=SumitODBC"    'this is where i am running into the problem i think

    strQuery = "SELECT getRollpHierRpt.Field1, ['App].[Master Book Name], ['App].[App Book Name], ['App].[Secondary App Book Name], ['App].[App Code], ['App].[App Book Status], ['App].[Book Transit], ['App].[Transit Desc], ['App].[Legal Entity Id], ['App].[Legal Entity Desc] FROM ['App] INNER JOIN getRollpHierRpt ON ['App].[Book Transit] = getRollpHierRpt.Field1;"

    Set resultSet = Connection.Execute(strQuery)

    Do While Not resultSet.EOF
        mainWorkBook.Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A" & intRowCounter).Value = resultSet.Fields("Master Book Name").Value
        mainWorkBook.Sheets("Sheet2").Range("B" & intRowCounter).Value = resultSet.Fields("App Book Name").Value
        intRowCounter = intRowCounter + 1
        resultSet.movenext
    Loop
    resultSet.Close
End Sub
```

Comment: Are you trying to `INNER JOIN` between the two excel files? Seems like you are calling one of the files ['app] and the other [getRollpHierRpt] in your sql statement?

Comment: So essentially  ['app] has 300,000 rows but i only want those raws where the column in  Book transit column in  ['app] matches those of getRollpHierRpt book transit column (field1)